# Rounding values to two decimals but still returning 10 decimals digits in Eclipse (Java)?

Tags: java, eclipse, matrix, double, rounding

I'm fairly new to this site. I had a question about rounding in Java.

The original code is long but I'll provide snippet of where my problem exits.

The following is one of the three matrices I have:

```
//European Put Option Matrix
    double[][] euroMatrix = new double[n+1][n+1];

    for(int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++){
        double j = K - americanMatrix[n][i];
        if(j >= 0)
            euroMatrix[n][i] = j;
    }
    double expTermNeg = (Math.exp((-1)*r * (T/n)));
    for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--){
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            euroMatrix[i][j] = 0.01*Math.floor((expTermNeg * (p*euroMatrix[i+1][j+1] + (1 - p)*euroMatrix[i+1][j]))*100.00);
        }
    }
```

Note that `americanMatrix[][]` displays all values that are within two decimals.

However, when I output the `euroMatrix[][]`, I get the following results:

```
22.0    14.689999999999998  5.479999999999997   0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Note that this is just the last row of the matrix.

I'm wondering why I'm getting values like `14.689999..`. when I clearly have the nice rounding trick of `(0.01 * Math.floor(x*100))`?

Also, how do you guys suggest I should fix it?

Comment: Use formatted output. Also, consider that some values aren't expressible, except as approximations, in binary (an equivalent in decimal is 1/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses `DecimalFormat` object to handle the output.  The cool thing is that `DecimalFormat.format()` can handle raw `double` values (see Autoboxing), so you can just pass in the values from your `euroMatrix` directly:

```
for (int i=n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j=0; j <= i; j++) {
        euroMatrix[i][j] = 0.01*Math.floor((expTermNeg * (p*euroMatrix[i+1][j+1] + (1 - p)*euroMatrix[i+1][j]))*100.00);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        String result = df.format(euroMatrix[i][j]);
        System.out.println(result); // prints 5.48 for 5.479999999999997
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried working with DecimalFormat before and then converting it back to double but it gave me errors on not being able to convert Long to Double.